# Multi column CSS Layout

Tags: css, layout

I am having a hard time trying to make this layout to work the way that I want.
As you can see the 4 columns appear outside of the wrapping div's and I don't know why.
Also the columns will be populated with a query so I need their height to be flexible but at the end I need all column to appear of the same height.

Here is the layout live www.onlinesportcenter.com

CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>layout</title>
    <style>
        body {

            margin:0;
            border:0;
            padding:0;
            height:100%;
            max-height:100%;
            background:#01245c;
            font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
            font-size:75%;
            overflow: hidden;

        }


        * html body {

            padding:116px 0 20px 0;

        }

        .header-wrap {

            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            height:116px;
            width:100%;
        }

        .header-wrap #header{

            margin:0 auto;
            position:relative;

        }

        #header {
            background: #666;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:1020px;
            height:116px;
            text-align:center;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;

        }

        * html #header {height:116px;}



        .container-wrap {

            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            margin-top:116px;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
        }

        .container-wrap #container {

            margin:0 auto;
            position:relative;
            top:0;
            height:100%;
        }

        #container {

            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1em;
            position:fixed;
            top:116px;
            left:0;
            bottom:20px;
            right:0;
            background:#fff;
            padding:0;
            width:1020px;

        }

        * html #container {

            height:100%;
            width:1020px;

        }

        #container img {margin:0;}


        #main {
            background:#fff;
            width:790px;
            height:100%;
            float:left;  
            overflow:auto;
        }

        .main-multi-form {
            background:#efefef;
            width:764px;
            margin:4px;
            border:1px solid #adadad;
            vertical-align:top;
        }

        .main-multi-form-bettype {
            background:#ddd;
            height: 50px;
            margin:8px 8px 0 8px;
            padding: 14px 0 0 0;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:top; 
        }

        .main-multi-form-bettype-extra {
            background:#dddddd;
            width:80%;
            height: 24px;
            vertical-align:top; 
            padding:0;
            margin:0 auto 0 auto;
            text-align:center;
        }

        .main-multi-form-events {
            background:#ddd;
            margin:8px 8px 8px 8px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:top;
            width: 748px;
        }

        .main-multi-form-column {
            background: #efefef;
            float:left;
            width:177px;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .main-multi-form-sports{
            background:#fff;
            border:1px solid #666;
            color: #333;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 1em;
            font-weight:bold;
            height: 18px;
            padding: 3px 0 0 0;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:top;
            width:175px;
        }

        .main-multi-form-leagues{
            padding: 0;
            text-align:left;
            vertical-align:top;
            width:177px;
            height:20px;

        }

        .main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox{
            float:left;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            vertical-align:top;
            width:20px; 
        }

        .main-multi-form-leagues-league{
            float:right;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            vertical-align:top;
            width:157px;
            height:20px;    
        }

        .main-multi-form-leagues-league a,a:Hover,a:Visited{
            color: #369;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 0.9em;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-decoration:none;
        }

        #right {

            width:228px;
            height:100%;
            float:right;  
            border-left:1px solid #73a2bd;
            border-right:1px solid #73a2bd;
            text-align:center;
        }


        .footer-wrap{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            height:20px;
            width:100%;

        }

        .footer-wrap #footer{

            position:relative;
            margin:0 auto;
        } 

        #footer {
          background: #666;
          position:absolute;
          bottom:0;
          left:0;
          width:1020px;
          height:19px;
          overflow:auto;
          text-align:center;
          border-top:1px solid #35759a;

        }

        * html #footer {height:20px;}

        #footer p {

          color:#fff;
          font-size:1em;
          margin:2px 0 0 0;

        }

        form {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        select {

            font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size:1em;
            color:#000000;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            vertical-align:top;
            font-size: 1em;
        }

        input {

            font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size:1em;
            color:#000000;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            vertical-align:top;
            font-size: 1em;
        }


        hr
        {
            width:100%;
            color: #000000;
            height: 1px;
        }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="header-wrap">  

    <div id="header">

        HEADER

    </div>

</div>

<div class="container-wrap">

    <div id="container">

        <div id="main">


            <div class="main-multi-form">



                            <div class="main-multi-form-bettype">

                                    TOP MAIN

                            </div>


                            <div class="main-multi-form-events">


                                    <div class="main-multi-form-column">


                                            <div class="main-multi-form-sports">Column 1</div>

                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                           <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="main-multi-form-column">


                                            <div class="main-multi-form-sports">Column 2</div>

                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                           <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="main-multi-form-column">


                                            <div class="main-multi-form-sports">Column 3</div>

                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                           <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="main-multi-form-column">


                                            <div class="main-multi-form-sports">Column 4</div>

                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                           <div class="main-multi-form-leagues">

                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-checkbox">

                                                        <input class="Selection-Checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox">

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="main-multi-form-leagues-league"><a href="#">CHECKBOX</a></div>

                                            </div>

                                    </div>

                            </div>

            </div>



        </div>

        <div id="right">
            <br /><br />
            RIGHT

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="footer-wrap">

    <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code suffers from severe _divitis_.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your float after you're done.

Add a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` at the end of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

add this to `.main-multi-form-events`

```
overflow:hidden;
zoom:1; /*for IE*/
```

do this to every container that has children that float. it makes the container wrap around those floating children. And also, do this to an element that is not supposed to wrap around it's floating sibling.

Comment: Excellent!  It worked very well.  But how do I make all columns even height?

Comment: Technique called *faux-columns* will let columns look like they are of same height (they won't be really, it's only a visual trick). Otherwise don't use floats but `display: table-cell` with `vertical-align: top` (and `display: table` on the container): that'll work for IE8+

Comment: I uploaded the changes to www.onlinesportcenter.com but even after ading the display: table-cell...  It doesn't want to expand.